# Is it possible to update a MySQL table directly from a table on a web page?

Tags: mysql, html-table

I have an html table on a webpage which pulls information from a MySQL table using PHP.  I would like to be able to edit one of the columns of this html table directly on the webpage, rather than having to go to PHP MyAdmin to do so, such the the MySQL table is also updated.  Is there a way of doing this?

[Here](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference-test.php) is an example of a table that I would like to edit.  Specifically I would like to edit the 'Paid Column' by clicking (or double-clicking or some similar method) in any of cells and editing the information in this cell.

Comment: Of course there is. As well as you can send a `SELECT` query to the database, you can the same with a `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. It depends on the way the data are provided.

Comment: I am not sure why you downvoted my question as I did research it first but didn't come up with a solution.  I regularly use `INSERT` to submit information from a form to a MySQL database, but I am not trying to do this now.  Rather I am wondering if I can edit the values directly in an HTML built from a MySQL database such that the MySQL database is also updated.

Comment: I do not know where you got the idea that I downvoted (I haven't downvoted anything today)...

Comment: Ok. Sorry. It's the first time I've had a question downvoted, so I was curious as to what I'd done wrong!

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is:

**Can I use PHP to make a sort of ADMIN page for MYSQL.**

It shouldn't surprise you that `PHPmyAdmin` is actually exactly that: a PHP page that changes your mysql. So **yes** you can, exactly the same way that phpmyadmin does it.

Now if your question is actually: how do I do this:

*Make an onchange on every field that does an AJAX call to a file that executes the correct SQL.*

Or you can use a "post" button if you don't want/need Async updates.

Comment: Thanks. To be more specific, what I am looking for is the simplest way of updating values in a particular column of an HTML table which is built from a MySQL table, directly in a webpage.  To be even more specific I have a column that has a default value of 0 when the user adds a new entry/row via a form, and I would like for myself and others, who don't have access to PHP MyAdmin, to be able to enter a new numeric value in the HTML table on the webpage, which would then update the MySQL table as well. I hope that's clear!

Comment: You have to make the column editable with input elements, put either each individual cell or the entire table in a form, and either onblur of an input field or onclick of a submit button, send the values to a php page for processing (either via ajax or a traditional post) and use the insert/update sql methods to save the data to your database.  There is no way for html to communicate with mysql beyond this type of approach.

Comment: Thanks.  That all makes good sense.  What I'm not sure how to do is to create the HTML table (using PHP) with the editable cells, such that it is both pulling the info from the MySQL table but is also an input field which is editable.

Comment: Use PHP to fill the fields of a form just like you would retrieve any info from your database. Then use javascript to call a separate PHP file (AJAX) whenever you change one of the cells. (onblur, onchange, etc will call a function, that function will do an ajax call to a php file that changes the database).

Answer (score 0):

you can write in a mysql with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NameOfTable
            (var1, var2, var3, var4)
         VALUES
            ('".$var1."',
            '".$var2."',
            '".$var3."',
            '".$var4."')";
   mysql_query($sql)
```

Is that what you was looking for?

Comment: Perhaps!  Normally I would enter values in to a MySQL table using the method you describe via a form.  Now I am wondering whether I can update the information already in the MySQL table directly from an HTML table that is generated from the MySQL table.  So I would need to be able to edit the values in the HTML table, and this would then update the MySQL table.  I hope this is clear!

Comment: As far as I know, you always have to tell php which vars need to be updated, which you do with a form, that can be update the mysql via javascript or via a classical post, but a possibility for the input fields are obviously necessarily... Sorry, but I still think I don't get your problem.

Comment: Hopefully it is clearer now I have updated my original question with a [link](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference-test.php) to the kind of table I would like to edit.

Comment: Yes, the exaple you posted is possible. You create the table as you did with the entries from the DB. You write the results in a form as pre entries `<INPUT NAME="feldname" SIZE=n MAXLENGTH=n VALUE="...">` than you execute a java script onchange of a field and let the java script update your DB and reload the table content from the DB